# Spring request using list as extension

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I was using spring 3.2.3. as you see, it deprecated mediaTypes that we used before to configure json processing, introducing an ContentNegotiationManager. Sound's great. But it annoys me.

I have xml configuration like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                            <entry key="list" value="application/json" />
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It seem's right. Em, I think so. But when I request an URL like /product.list, which match a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product.list", consumes={"application/json"}, produces=    {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Object list(@RequestBody ListProductReq listProductReq) throws BusinessException
```

this method only accept json request, everything works great, except URL with list extension. After a long time trace, I found that no matter what I configured in xml, just like things that I mentioned above, there will be an `org.springframework.web.accept.ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy` and `org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy`, I don't know where it came from, cause nowhere else can I set these things. The debug info like the picture I attached below.

[image]

The debug info was captured from class `ContentNegotiationManager`.

I wonder if some one came across this problem, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <entry key="list" value="application/json" />
```

this is not valid. From the  [PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC2/api/org/springframework/web/accept/PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.html) javadocs:

> A ContentNegotiationStrategy that uses the path extension of the URL
>   to determine what **media types** are requested. The path  extension
>   is first looked up in the map of media types provided to the
>   constructor. If that fails, the Java Activation framework is used as a
>   fallback mechanism.

**.list** is not a valid media type. Its just a URL pattern.

Change your `@RequestMapping(value="/product.list")`  to `@RequestMapping(value="/product")`

Check if you have valid Jackson libraries in your classpath.

Comment: Hi, Bhaskara, I have Jackson libraries in my classpath, and everything that has another extension works great, like `product.update`, `product.add` and so on. But list extension was map to `text/plain`, this is the main problem. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an solution to deal with it.

By specifying content-negotiation-manager when using mvc:annotation-driven，then set favorPathExtension to false. Problem will be solved.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="negotiationManager"></mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="negotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks anyway.